# Missing directive of assembly reference

Tags: c#, reference, using

I added an existing form (and its references) to another project and I am trying to show the new form. There are no coding issues, just a reference error:

> The type or namespace 'frmEmail' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

I cannot figure out what "using" or reference I failed to use when importing the other form. Any ideas?

Here is the code causing the error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Notify_Setup
{
public partial class frmNotifications : Form
{
    public frmNotifications()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pbBlue.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(pbBlue_MouseEnter);
    }
    private void pbGreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmEmail frmEmail = new frmEmail();
        frmEmail.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How do you think we can help if you don't show us your code?

Comment: Open the source code of your form, navigate to the top, and see the intellisense error shown by VS.

Comment: Go to where the namespace is defined for your frmEmail (the top of the file).  It will probably be the namespace of your original code.  Change this to the new code namespacing

Comment: What namespace is `frmEmail` in? If it's different than the one that `frmNotifications` lives in then you need to add it with a `using` statement. Also, if it's in a different assembly, then you need to add a reference in your project to the other assemble. In other words, exactly what the error message says.

Comment: Another shortcut in Visual Studio is to right click and see if there's a "Resolve" option in the context menu. If there is, you can click it to automatically either fully qualify your class name or add the using statement. If it's not there, then you are probably missing the reference to the assembly.

Comment: @Joshua: Changing the namespace to fix this error is, generally, not the solution. Namespaces exist for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull the namespace in. For example, if this was how your form currently was in the other project:

```
namespace Your.Form.Namespace { // this is important
    public class YourForm : Form {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Then in the project you're adding it to.. you need to add your assembly as a reference, then import the namespace in like this:

```
using Your.Form.Namespace; // import the namespace

namespace Other.Project {
    public class OtherClass {
        YourForm _form; // this is fine now
    }
}
```

The other options is to fully qualify the type. What this means, is to use the entire namespace and type name in the declaration. It would be like this:

```
namespace Other.Project {
    public class OtherClass {
        Your.Form.Namespace.YourForm _form; // this is fine too
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I added an existing form (and it's references) to another project and I am trying to show the new form.

It looks like the form you added was `frmNotifications`, but is creating an instance of `frmEmail`. Did you also added it?